# How make a curved line animation on JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make theme change animation like in layout [here (file mp4)](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1085999197070831717/1134934056799326258/video_2023-07-29_22-41-03.mp4), but I don't know how to make the line curved, tell me please

Here is the code that I was able to write https://codepen.io/mmorrii/pen/yLQQjrv

HTML

```html
<div class="button">
  <button id="button-theme" type="button">theme</button>
</div>

<div class="circle"></div>
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let button = document.getElementById("button-theme");
  let circle = document.querySelector(".circle");

  button.onclick = () => {
    circle.classList.toggle("play");
  };

  document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
    const mouseX = event.clientX;
    const mouseY = event.clientY;

    circle.style.left = mouseX - circle.offsetWidth / 2 + "px";
    circle.style.top = mouseY - circle.offsetHeight / 2 + "px";
  });
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/bezierCurveTo